# Property or indexer 'System.IO.FileInfo.Length' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, fileinfo

How can i assign Property `System.IO.FileInfo.Length`?

[FileInfo.Length Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It is read only!

Comment: Why do you need to? The `FileInfo` class exists for the purpose of _getting file information_, not manipulating it. -- So the answer is: you can't. You would have to create your own class for that.

Comment: How can i write that class?

Comment: [`FileStream.SetLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx)

Comment: You can only mark one answer :). Go with Eli's, he was first to point it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FileInfo.Length is used to get the size of a file, the only way to change a file size is by modifying it's content

Comment: @MoonLight : But he's right. Now you're just being ungrateful. It's read-only. You cannot change it. Period. And I would still like to know _why_ you need to do this.

Comment: @MoonLight - I don't understand - what would be the purpose of removing the answer to "let other people answer"? It doesn't make any sense to do, especially if it's correct

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a file's size programmatically you would have to write something to it. The simplest way would probably be to just fill it with zeros.

```
public void writeEmptyFile(string path, int size)
{
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        fs.Write(new byte[size], 0, size);
    }
}
```

This method will either **A)** write a new file containing null-bytes (the file will have the specified size), or **B)** if the file `path` already exists it will append the specified amount of null-bytes to that file, increasing it's size.